# Can I access Gmail through SSL?

Tags: gmail, https, ssl

Is there a way to access Gmail securely over SSL?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because using SSL has become mandatory. Related: [How to access Gmail with HTTP?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/59712/88163)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, just add an "s" to the http in the address bar - so to get to Gmail over SSL, type in:

https://www.gmail.com

You can also change a setting in Gmail to [require your account to use SSL](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=74765):

> We've recently made the 'Always use https' setting the default behavior in Gmail (the default used to be http). Here's some background: If you sign in to Gmail via a non-secure Internet connection, like a public wireless or non-encrypted network, your Google account may be more vulnerable to hijacking. Non-secure networks make it easier for someone to impersonate you and gain full access to your Google account, including any sensitive data it may contain like bank statements or online log-in credentials. Accordingly, we enable the 'Always use https' option in Gmail by default. HTTPS, or Hypertext Transfer Protocol Secure, is a secure protocol that provides authenticated and encrypted communication.

In your Gmail settings, under the General tab, select "Always use https":

[image]

Comment: The option to use Gmail without SSL is no longer available.

Answer (score 16):

Gmail now uses https by default.

> #### [Default https access for Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/default-https-access-for-gmail.html)
>
> We are currently rolling out default https for everyone. If you've previously set your own https preference from Gmail Settings, nothing will change for your account. If you trust the security of your network and don't want default https turned on for performance reasons, you can turn it off at any time by choosing "Don't always use https" from the Settings menu.

Comment: Can you provide a citation please?

Comment: Here is the announcement post: http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/default-https-access-for-gmail.html

Comment: I'm reasonably certain that they've also removed the ability to turn off https.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Within Settings of Gmail, go to the General tab then scroll down to the Browser Connection setting.  There you can select to use http or https for connections to Gmail

Answer (score -1):

Under Settings there is an option to choose the Browser Connection method. Just select "Always use https".

If you are using Google Apps, this can be set at a domain level by going to Manage this Domain -> Domain Settings -> Enable SSL (Automatically enforce Secure Socket Layer (SSL) connections when your users access Gmail, Calendar, Docs, and Sites.)